# Excel Formula with dynamic input range

Tags: arrays, excel, dynamic, excel-formula

I have the following problem. I use excel's SLOPE function. However, I constantly have to adjust the input range manually -> eg sometimes its SLOPE(A2:A50) and then SLOPE(A2:A75), depending how many input variables I have.

Is there a way I can change the function so that it always takes the range up until the last non-empty cell so that I don't have to adjust manually every time?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Search google for a `dynamic named range` then your formula is just `=SLOPE(name)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Simple Explanation  : 
You can just use an intermediate cell to calculate your ranges and then pass those values to the slope function

In the below Example , if X and Y are extended to have any number of obs , the formula will calculate it dynamically.

[image]